# Error when click on Subscription confirmation link

Tags: exm

Using the below mentioned code for adding contact in List manager using EXM in SXA Sitecore 9.1.1.

```
 public ISubscriptionManager SubscriptionManager { get; }

 public EmailSubscriptionRepository(ISubscriptionManager subscriptionManager)
        {
            SubscriptionManager = subscriptionManager;
        }
```

After injecting this we are using below code

```
  SubscriptionManager.Subscribe(contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault(), Guid.Parse(emailCampaignId), true);
```

This code is working fine and sending a Subscription confirmation email but when we click on the link which is mentioned in the mail it stuck on below url

```
https://domainname/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/ConfirmSubscription.aspx?ec_subscr=9J6G6D2D2184B60B6E00A8ECE41RFED
```

Comment: Have you defined `Final Confirmation Page - The page displayed after a visitor changes their subscription:` on your EXM Manager Root?

Comment: It was not defined and after adding it . It is working , thanks

Comment: Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define

```
Final Confirmation Page - The page displayed after a visitor changes their subscription:
```

on your `EXM Manager Root` item.

Then Sitecore will redirect you to that page after subscription confirmation.